# How to merge a string and a awesome icon in android?

Tags: java, android, font-awesome

Activity :

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");

Button btn_enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_enter );

btn_enter.setTypeface(font);

btn_enter.setText(R.string.fa_lock_open  + "Sign in");
```

values/string :
`<string name="fa_user_plus"> &#xf234; </string>`

The text that is displayed  :  **2131623982SIGN IN**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
btn_enter.setText(getString(R.string.fa_lock_open)  + "Sign in");
```

R.string.fa_lock_open will return int value. When you will use the method getString() then you will get the string that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use drawables for icon and set icon to left using this code

```
Btn_enter.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i want to use a `awesome icon` instead of `drawable.icon`